# i want to display data that is in database into grid view control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ado.net

i want to retrieve the data stored in the table of the database into gridview control and my ado code is

```
   public void retrieve_client()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBconnection.connectstr);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("retrieve_client", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.name;
        SqlDataReader r = com.ExecuteReader();
        if(r.HasRows)
        {
            if(r.Read())
            {
                this.name =    r[0].ToString();
                this.address = r[1].ToString();
                this.phone =   r[1].ToString();
            }
        }
        r.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
```

and my web form source is i want to enter the name in text box and retrieve the data and displaying them into grid view control please answer me:

my web form source is:

```
    <table>
<tr>
    <td>

        <label class="labelclient">Name</label>
            </td>

    <td class="clientpadding">

        <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox_retrieveclientbyname_first" runat="server" placeholder=" First Name" cssclass="textboxstyle" required="required"></asp:TextBox>

        &nbsp; &nbsp; 


            <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox_retrieveclientbyname_second" runat="server" placeholder=" Second Name" CssClass="textboxstyle" required="required"></asp:TextBox>

         &nbsp; &nbsp; 

    <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox_retrieveclientbyname_third" runat="server" placeholder=" Third Name" CssClass="textboxstyle" required="required"></asp:TextBox>

      </td>

</tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="buttontd">
            <asp:Button ID="btn_find_clientbyname" runat="server" Text="Find" CssClass="addclientbutton" OnClick="btn_find_clientbyname_Click"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_ermsg" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView_clientbyname" runat="server" >
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridheader"/>
        <RowStyle CssClass="gridrow" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle cssclass="gridaltrow" />
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use `DataAdapter` to Fill `DataTable` And bind the `GridView` With
>   That `DataTable`

```
 public void retrieve_client()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBconnection.connectstr);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("retrieve_client", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.name;
        SqlDataAdapter da = New SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataTable dt=New DatTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        GridView_clientbyname.DataSource=dt;
        GridView_clientbyname.DataBind();

    }
```